# Print PHP string in new lines

Tags: php

Anything wrong with this code? I want it to print the name and address - each on a separate line, but it all comes up in one line.

Here's the code

```
<?php 

    $myname = $_POST['myname'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $address3 = $_POST['address3'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $county = $_POST['county'];

    $content = '';

        $content .="My name    = " .$myname ."\r\n";
        $content .="Address1   = " .$address1 ."\n";
        $content .="Address2   = " .$address2 ."\n"; 
        $content .="Address3   = " .$address3 ."\n"; 
        $content .="town       = " .$town ."\n"; 
        $content .="county     = " .$county ."\n"; 

        echo $content;

?>
```

It looks like the '\n' character is not working.

Comment: If this is on a HTML page, you need to use HTML line breaks: `<br>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your source code this will show on a next line, but if you want to go to another line in HTML you will have to append `<br />`.

So:

```
$content .="My name    = " .$myname ."<br />\r\n";
```

I left the `\r\n` here because it will go to the next line in your source code aswell, which might look nicer if you have to view the source.

Answer (score 3):

The `\n` character properly works just fine. The problem is, it's not what you expect.

If you see this in a browser, you won't see line breaks, because line breaks are ignored in the source code. The HTML parser only reads `<br>` as line breaks.

If you try to go to your website and view the source code, you'll find that the line breaks are in there.